# Custom Application class onCreate() never called

Tags: android

I'm trying to initialize Parse on a custom Application class:

```
import android.app.Application;
import android.util.Log;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.SaveCallback;

public class SomeApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initializeParse();
    }

    private void initializeParse() {
        Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("##########")
                .clientKey("############")
                .server("https://#####.com/parse/")
                .build()
        );
        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                // Do something here
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And I already declare this Application in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.someproject">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".SomeApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".AnotherActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But my custom Application is never called. I tried to put logs and break points on onCreate method, clean project, rebuild project, close and re-open Android Studio, uninstall and reinstall the app and nothing ... so, I need help.

**Thanks!**

Comment: How do you check it is never called, debug? Log, smthn else?

Comment: Have you declared intent-flags in activities from which this activity is being called?

Comment: @ViktorYakunin Yes! Logs, breakpoints, System.out ...

Comment: @Swr7der It's an Application class, not an Activity ...

Comment: you should have entry point to start your application, that could be Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: @ViktorYakunin I have an entry point. Is my MainActivity class. And it's in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Are you sure that your app closes before the relaunch? And not just simply goes to the background? Can you manually close the app and run the project?

Comment: @Akeshwar I closed and reopened, uninstalled and reinstalled and nothing change (I forgot to say that on question)

Comment: Not much clue then. All I can ask now: 1. Is the class `SomeApplication` in the same package in which your `MainActivity` is? and 2. Are the methods in your `MainActivity` getting called?

Comment: @Akeshwar 1. Yes, MainActivity is in same package of SomeApplication. 2. Yes, the methods in MainActivity are getting called normally.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disable Instant Run, Clean build, Rebuild the project and then run again.
I had the same issue. Disabling instant run worked for me. It is weird Application class not getting called. But it happened.

Comment: I spent half day trying to figure it out and in the end it was instant run.
This is the last time i use this feature!
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, you save a lot of my time.

Comment: Works if disable the instant run. Enabling again gives the same error.

Comment: Nothing weird about it. If Instant Run was the "problem" the application class had to be initialized once at least. It was exactly the point of Instant Run that the entire initialization does not have to be run through again and again if you only wanted to test small changes "in the middle". And didn't Instant Run have an extra button like "Apply Code Changes" nowadays? Then the solution would have been simply not to press it.

Comment: When this issue happened, I didn't run the app through Instant Run. It was a normal run which means it is expected that our custom application class should be called.
Fortunately, these kinds of bugs are not happening in the new "Apply Code Changes" feature - it doesn't affect anything as long as we don't press it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I forgot about declaration in the manifest:

```
<application 
    android:name=".App" 
...>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - try using this property in your Manifest file:

```
<application 
android:name=".SomeApplication"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Exactly the same as Ivan wrote 2 years earlier...