# Application onCreate() never called

Tags: android

For some reason my app won't call custom application classes `onCreate()` anymore. Yesterday everything was fine but today my app crashes when it tries to open a connection to Realm.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call 'Realm.init(Context)' before calling this method.`

Since I do initialize Realm in my custom application classes `onCreate()` I tried inserting a breakpoint and logging out of the method. Nothing.

This question had a similiar problem

[Custom Application class onCreate() never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40662232/custom-application-class-oncreate-never-called)

I have disabled instant run, cleaned, rebuilt and even restarted android studio but the problem persists. I even tried checking out a commit from three days ago, which was most certainly working, but the result is the same.

Custom application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
        Realm.init(this);
        //more Realm initialization code
    }
}
```

Manifest's application section

```
 <application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme">
```

Any ideas what might cause this and how to get it fixed?

**EDIT**

Everything logcat puts out before crash

```
03-19 21:06:10.687 21869-21869/? E/Zygote: v2
03-19 21:06:10.687 21869-21869/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10323
03-19 21:06:10.687 21869-21869/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
03-19 21:06:10.688 21869-21869/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
03-19 21:06:10.688 21869-21869/? W/SELinux: SELinux selinux_android_compute_policy_index : Policy Index[2],  Con:u:r:zygote:s0 RAM:SEPF_SECMOBILE_7.0_0004, [-1 -1 -1 -1 0 1]
03-19 21:06:10.689 21869-21869/? I/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=untrusted, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=hailer.com.hailer 
03-19 21:06:10.692 21869-21869/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
03-19 21:06:10.709 21869-21869/? D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
03-19 21:06:10.709 21869-21869/? D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
03-19 21:06:10.790 21869-21869/hailer.com.hailer D/ContextRelationMgrBrdg: loadKlass() : caller=com.samsung.android.bridge.multiscreen.common.ContextRelationManagerBridge.<clinit>:28 android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication:833 
03-19 21:06:10.814 21869-21869/hailer.com.hailer W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
03-19 21:06:10.872 21869-21869/hailer.com.hailer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-19 21:06:10.873 21869-21869/hailer.com.hailer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                   Process: hailer.com.hailer, PID: 21869
                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{hailer.com.hailer/hailer.com.hailer.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before calling this method.
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2947)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Call `Realm.init(Context)` before calling this method.
                                                                       at io.realm.Realm.getDefaultInstance(Realm.java:208)
                                                                       at hailer.com.hailer.adapters.DiscussionAdapter.<init>(DiscussionAdapter.java:57)
                                                                       at hailer.com.hailer.fragments.ChatListFragment.onCreateView(ChatListFragment.java:60)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2189)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1299)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:757)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2355)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2146)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2098)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2008)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
                                                                       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
                                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
                                                                       at hailer.com.hailer.activities.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:320)
                                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1256)
                                                                       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6929)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2910)
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3008) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
                                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688) 
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

**UPDATE**

I trimmed down the libraries and disabled multidexing. Didn't help. I also went trough the DiscussionAdapter and ChatListFragment and both are fine. Realm is used in a correct manner and has worked for over a year without issues. I also have `log.d("CUSTOMAPPCLS","onCreate called")` in my custom application class which does not show in the log. Nor does a breakpoint stop in any part of the `onCreate()` call.

Now I got a new error. This time it's from PrefsAccessor - a wrapper for SharedPreferences which is also intialised in the custom applications `onCreate` call. `PrefAccessor.init(this);` I ran the build again but got the Realm error... The one considering PrefAccessor threw a nullpointer execption when trying to access the SharedPreferences. This further points to the fact that the application `onCreate` isn't called.

```
    public static string isUseEnterToSendEnabled()
    {
    SharedPreferences prefs = applicationContext.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);// <-- nullpointer exception: Trying to call .getSharedPreferences on a null object
    return prefs.getBoolean(ENTER_TO_SEND, false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the logs after your run

Comment: Sure. I'll edit them in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realm - Realm.init(this) failed in onCreate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40167694/realm-realm-initthis-failed-in-oncreate)

Comment: Check the merged manifest in `<app>/build/intermediates/manifests/full` that the the `application` in manifest comes out all right. For example it's possible you have a later dependency somewhere that overwrites the application tag in manifest merging process.

Comment: I checked the merged manifest and it was in order. No overwrites nor other oddities.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but if the build cache is being used, you might want to try cleaning build cache and see if it changes your result. http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/build-cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE 04/2017
The Samsung S7 started working couple of days after I posted this answer... Black magics all the way I say.

---

It seems that the Samsung S7 that I usually use for testing is somehow busted. I got some other phones from the office and all of them work just fine. I really have no idea what caused the phone to start crashing the app... None of the other apps are crashing and I didn't download any updates or other apps before this started. I'll post a comment to this answer if I figure this one out and accept this as the solution since I found a "solution"....

Answer (score 1):

I found similar scenario to yours here:

https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1800

The issue seems to be about having lots of libraries included to your project (such as Google Play Services) which might led to your app hitting the 65K methods limit.

Did you include any new dependencies to your project?

### UPDATE:

after checking your log, I believe the problem can be here:

> hailer.com.hailer.adapters.DiscussionAdapter.(DiscussionAdapter.java:57)
>                                                                          at
>   hailer.com.hailer.fragments.ChatListFragment.onCreateView(ChatListFragment.java:60)

Maybe in your **ChatListFragment**, you have an instance of **DiscussionAdapter**  which in turn has some static initializer that invokes something related to Realm.

Comment: No I did not. I do have the whole google play services library included and multidexing enabled... I'll trim it down and post the results.

Comment: Please check the DiscussionAdapter, it may contain a static initializer block or some static Real managed objects. This may be the cause of the crash.

Comment: They aren't the cause of this. Those classes have been fully functional over a year, but they do contain the first call to `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` in the whole app, which is why they show up on the stacktrace.